# Calendar with freely adjustable notification time

Tags: android, open-source, calendar

I am looking for a Free Software Calendar app for Android 10+. I'm using Lineage OS which comes with [`org.lineageos.etar`](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Etar) which is 99% what I want:

- Free software.
- Month view.
- Week, day & agenda view.
- Uses Android calendar sync. Works with Google Calendar, Exchange, etc.
- Support offline calendar.
- Agenda widget.
- Recurring events that can also be edited individually.

Except for one feature:

- [Being able to adjust the notification time for an event freely.](https://github.com/Etar-Group/Etar-Calendar/issues/314)

Etar only allows 0, 1, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 or 45 minutes, 1, 2, 3, 12 or 24 hours, 2 days or 1 week to be selected via a drop-down box. I vaguely remember having a very similar-looking Calendar app on CyanogenMod (back when that was a thing) which had that capability, but I'm not sure which one it was or whether that's still around and up-to date enough to be used.

Ideally, the app should be available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/).